# It is possible to call a constructor explicitly after executing some code?

Tags: c++, constructor

I want to do some processing before calling the second constructor. For example:

```
class Foo {
    Foo(){ displayWindow(); }

    //This is possible
    Foo(int bar) : Foo() { windowSize = bar; }

    //But how do I do processing before calling the second constructor?
    Foo(int bar, int baz) {
        addLabel(baz); // prototype = void addLabel(int)
        Foo(bar);
    }
}
```

How would I accomplish this (without using initialization functions)?

EDIT: I updated the example. It now shows that the default constructor HAS to occur last. If it doesnt, displayWindow wont take into account any of the updated variables.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When you are constructing objects just for the purpose of calling their constructor it is not really an object constructor that you need.

Comment: I agree with pmr, but I will also add that all I can really see is how to do it with initialization and even that is iffy since initialization ordering can be tricky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
Foo(int bar, int baz) :
    Foo(initializeAnotherStaticLibrary(bar, baz) == -1 ? bar : baz)
{
}
```

(Note that delegating constructors is a feature supported only in C++11 onward.)

Comment: @chacham15: What do you mean? If I understand, yes, you have a single expression to figure out what to do, which makes it hard to do this in general. Sometimes making helper initializer functions is the way to go, though in your case it works out nicely.

Comment: I tried this out and this doesnt work either since `error: type 'Foo' is not a direct base of 'Foo'`.

Comment: @chacham15: Are you using a C++11 compiler?

Comment: yup, `g++ -v` produces `gcc version 4.6.3 20111127 (prerelease) (pcx32)`

Comment: @chacham15: [It wasn't added until version 4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).

Comment: why not `Foo(int bar, int baz) :Foo((addLabel(baz),bar)) {}`?  Much shorter.  Or a [named constructor](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/named-ctor-idiom.html).

Comment: thanks @GManNickG, MooingDuck, addLabel is a void function. Named constructor is cool though.

Comment: @chacham15: MooingDuck is using the comma operator.

Answer (score 0):

If there are sensible defaults, use them.  That'd sidestep the whole issue of how to call the other constructors, cause there's only one.  :)

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(int bar = 100, int baz = 0) {
        if (baz) addLabel(baz);
        displayWindow();
        windowSize = bar;
    }
};
```

Although i question the idea of calling `displayWindow()` in the constructor anyway.  Besides the ugliness of getting to work before you've even completely initialized *yourself*...what happens if the object isn't done being constructed yet?  (For example, if you have a subclass of `Foo`, its constructor will run after this -- and if you have any virtual stuff, the vtables probably don't point where you think they do...)

Answer (score -1):

I have found that this is possible via the placement operator:

```
class Foo {
    Foo(){ displayWindow(); }

    //This is not possible either, since "type 'Foo' is not a direct base of 'Foo'"
    Foo(int bar) : Foo() { windowSize = bar; }

    //This is the solution using the placement operator
    Foo(int bar, int baz) {
        addLabel(baz);
        new (this) Foo(bar);
    }
}
```

I have heard that there are caveats to this, if anyone can point them out, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Well, all the base classes and members are already constructed at that point, so you completely clobber them by initializing again. You need to call their destructors first (and then the base class destructors). But then this has the problem that upon second construction you *must* succeed and not throw any exceptions, or the destructors of the bases and members will be run, *but they've already been destructed*. So now you need to check that every base and every member has no exceptions on destruction and construction, just to get this to work. All to avoid adding a function?